# How to get back the Spotlight For Help menu item

Tags: macos, cocoa, menu, menuitem, spotlight

I have an application that requires authentication. Before the user authenticates only a subset of menu items is present in the menu bar. After the user has successfully authenticated I replace the application’s main menu with `[NSApp setMainMenu:aMainMenu];` Unfortunately this removes the Spotlight For Help menu item that allows the user to search for menu items and inside the help book. The menu item is present before I replace the main menu.

How can I get the Spotlight For Help menu item back without replacing specific menu items instead of the whole main menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you resetting your main menu, do it without your new help menu built in.  Keep that part separate...

... because after resetting your main menu, you will *also* need to reset your help menu via [`[NSApp setHelpMenu:];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/setHelpMenu%3a) (and I've linked Apple's documentation for you).  That is what will reinstall Spotlight for Help.

Comment: What I do now is `[NSApp setMainMenu:self.mainMenu]; [NSApp setHelpMenu:[[self.mainMenu itemAtIndex:[self.mainMenu numberOfItems] - 1] submenu]];` and it works without problems. Thank you very much Michael.